# Supplied values does not match table definition. ID not auto-generated

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have created a SQL table with 17 columns. 16 of them are my own generated data (ints, dates etc) and then last column is an ID that I created using:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[my_table](
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,

 CONSTRAINT [PK_Supplier] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

So I have created a data frame and now I need to put it into my SQL table via a Python script. Roughly speaking I try to do this by:

```
insert_statement = """
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[my_table]
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
"""

for record in df.values.tolist():
    cursor.execute(insert_statement, record)
```

Where my `df` is a data frame with 16 rows (no id though).

When I run this I get the error `Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition`. I get that the error is that I am providing less input than the dimensions of the SQL table, i.e. 16 columns vs 17. However, I was under the impression that the ID in the SQL table was auto-generated when I put data into the table ? Do I really have to provide the ID number myself, or am I just missing something ?

Comment: If you define your `INSERT` clause with a column list, which you should be doing anyway, this error will go away.

Comment: Yes, I have a data frame with something like a 1000 rows that is generated one time each day with new data. When that data frame has been created I wish to upload/insert that data into a SQL database so my self, and others, can quickly access the data.

Comment: @AndrewCorrigan, why I deleted the comments; though the DDL is misleading and likely thus not needed. *"name the columns in the insert"* This is what I said: *"define your `INSERT` clause with a column list"*

Comment: Yeah, I pressed enter and your comment disappeared - was about to edit it

Comment: @Larnu, so I need to specify the column names instead of just VALUES(?,?,?...), or...? (I'm fairly new to SQL, so sorry for the lack of understanding.

Comment: You need to define the column in your `INSERT` clause, @DenverDang , like show in the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#c-inserting-data-that-is-not-in-the-same-order-as-the-table-columns)

Comment: `INSERT INTO [dbo].[my_table] (Col1, Col2, ...... ) VALUES (?, ?, ......);` Note that this issue has nothing whatsoever to do with Python so have removed the tag